# How to restrict slot filling in RASA?

Tags: rasa, rasa-core

how to decide which slot to be filled at a time? How to have control over slot filling?

eg: need to collect details for a hotel room booking, slots are hotel name, person name
There is a hotel name "Hotel Michael" (synonym: michael), and if the chatbot asks for the hotel name and user types "Michael" it will be extracted as enity hotel_name and PERSON. Thereby filling two slots at the same time.

I tried collecting details through two different form, but it didn't work, in both forms, both slots are filled at the same time (and i am not sure if i am doing it right)

Comment: I'd recommend to have a look at disabling auto-slot filling (see [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/next/domain#slot-auto-fill)) and/or custom slot mappings (see [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/2.5.x/forms#custom-slot-mappings)). Please feel free to post on the [forum](https://forum.rasa.com) if your problem(s) persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom slot mapping . please refer this forum
https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-restrict-slot-filling/46598/11